# memory limit set in php.ini not working in script

Tags: php, php-ini

I have set memory_limit to 256M in php.ini file and restarted the server.

```
memory_limit=256M
```

And

```
ini_get("memory_limit") -> returns 256M
```

But i will get error as "Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4681469 bytes) in /home/../PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 282" (which is 64M).

Comment: did u set memory as ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); ?? in script?

Comment: No.. I have set in php.ini file only

Comment: check is your memory changed or not by echo phpinfo();exit; and find memory_limit

Comment: I have checked phpinfo(); memory_limit is 256M

Comment: alright, yes checked, well, instead of changing in ini file, use ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in your file at top

Comment: even in htaccess file, add php_value memory_limit 256M

Comment: I have tried both, but didn't worked

Comment: than increase the memory as 512 and check

Comment: I can increase the limit, but i have concern with the error log which says Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Comment: It seems you only have 64M allocated to script... but i should be work after change it to 256M.. well just for testing increase it but not in ini file use in  ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

Comment: I have added ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in my script and tried, still i'm having the same issue

Comment: I am working on phpexcel, there are around 5000 rows & 11 columns. This issue arises while exporting data into excel file. Same issue does not arise when i'm querying mysql and displaying results on screen. This seems to be a specific issue with the log that shows 64M is exhausted

Comment: sorry it should be  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

Comment: if you are facing same issue again than release memory first and than use ini_set function. ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); release

Comment: I have tried with 512M and -1 still the same issue

Comment: Can you search if somewhere else in your code, someone calls  ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');?

Comment: @Adrien thank you, i have found code ini_set('memory_limit', '64M') in excel's CacheBase.php file, after removing this it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in your console:

```
mysql -u root -p123456
show variables like 'max%';
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=128*1024;
```

Where `root` is my mysql username and `123456` is the password

Comment: why did mysql come into picture? It's issue with php script

Comment: I am working on phpexcel, there are around 5000 rows & 11 columns. This is issue arises while exporting data into excel file. Same issue does not arise when i'm querying mysql and displaying results on screen. This seems to be a specific issue with the log that shows 64M is exhausted

Comment: Try ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in you php file

Comment: I have added ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in my php file and tried, still i'm having the same issue